# Homebrew running update && upgrade error: Another active Homebrew update process is already in progress

Tags: homebrew

Recently on MacOS 10.14.3 I started getting error when I run following two commands together:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
```

> Error: Another active Homebrew update process is already in progress.
>   Please wait for it to finish or terminate it to continue.

If I run `brew update` I get following messages:

> Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
>   See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
>   Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).

and then immediately `brew upgrade` I get the same error as if I run two commands together.

It seems like `brew update` is running in the background and that stops `brew upgrade` from running. After some arbitrary amount of time passes, I can run `brew upgrade` without error.

Is there a way to know when `brew update` is truly done?
Is there a way to force `brew update` to run in foreground?